# copy range and paste to specific cells on another worksheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am new to this forum.

1. I want to copy range `a1:a10` from `sheet 1` and past into cells on `sheet 2` start from `a10` in increase of 10 cells. i.e.:

   - Content of `sheet1:a1` on `sheet2:a10`;
   - Content of `sheet1:a2` on `sheet2:a20`;
   - Content of `sheet1:a3` on `sheet2:a30`;
   - ... and so on...

I know the code to simple range copy and paste as below

```
Sub Copy(
Dim CopyFrom As Range

Set CopyFrom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2 : A10")
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value

End Sub
```

Please help by editing the code above to suite my need.

2. Hide number of rows based on values in cells. i.e., if cell `a1` contains 10 and cell `a2` contains 50, it should hide rows 10 to 50.

I can do the above by setting one value as fixed and calling one value from cell but not both.

```
Sub AUTOHIDE_ROWS_307()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Dim Cval As Variant
Dim Rng1 As Range
Cval = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Value
Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A50:N" & Cval)
Rng1.Activate
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please help by editing above to suit my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a code for me service nor is it a teach me to code service.  If you have existing code that is not working post it in the original post using edit and explain what the code is doing in error and we will help overcome specific errors.

Comment: I have added codes as requested which works partially for me...@ScottCraner

Comment: No, we're not going to *edit above* to suit your needs. **You** should edit the code to suit your needs. If you run into problems doing so, you can then post here, explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of **your code**, and ask a specific question about that code. This is not a code editing or rewrite service, and we're not anyone's personal coding assistants. We're glad to help, but we're not doing it for you.

Comment: people should not neg on others if they are expert of doing things on their own. I am asking for help I have asked for suggesting what can be solution and not to rewrite codes.. I have read thousands of question on this website when people help to response and provide full solution and not just Neg about... Let me know if you want me to delete my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
Dim I as Integer
For I = 1 To 10
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, I * 10) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, I)
Next
```

2.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A" & .Range("A1").Value, "A" & .Range("A2").Value).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With
```

Comment: THE ABOVE SOLUTION FOR HIDING ROWS APPEAR NOT WORKING IT GIVES COMPILE ERROR, SYNTEX ERROR

Comment: Sorry, one too many brackets, and I must have done my copy/paste into the answer before I found that bug when I tested it.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELPING FOR BOTH THE ANSWER... WORKS LIKE CHARM... .. MUCH APPRICIATED @YowE3K

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the purpose of this forum, but you are so lost here that'll give you something that you can use as a starting point.

```
Sub doThatCopy()
    'Create your variables
    Dim myFormerSheetRow, myDestinationSheetRow, myFormerColumn, myDestinationColumn As Integer
    Dim myFormerSheetName, myDestinationSheetName As String

    'Setting the variables first values
    myFormerColumn = 1 ' 1 = A, 2 = B...
    myDestinationColumn = 3 '3 = C
    myFormerSheetRow = 0 ' This row, doesn't exists, but we'll increment it before first use
    myDestinationSheetRow = 1

    myFormerSheetName = "Sheet1"
    myDestinationSheetName = "Sheet2"

    For i = 1 To 10
        'You could use  "myFormerSheetRow = i" instead of the row below, but I'll leave it this way to be more understandable for you
        myFormerSheetRow = myFormerSheetRow + 1
        myDestinationSheetRow = myFormerSheetRow * 10
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(myDestinationSheetName).Cells(myDestinationSheetRow, myDestinationColumn).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(myFormerSheetName).Cells(myFormerSheetRow, myFormerColumn).Value
    Next i

    MsgBox ("Success!")
End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS FOR HELP... MUCH APPRICIATED @Diogopaim